# MySQL 5.5 metadata lock delays table drop

Tags: mysql, metadata, innodb, locks

I was doing some tests with table compression and killed a large (138M rows) insert. I went to drop the table this morning and it's taking a very long time. I checked the process list

```
| 39 | root | localhost | cdr3 | Killed  | 72959 | query end                       | insert into cdr3_test_4 select * from cdr3_v1 |
| 44 | root | localhost | cdr3 | Query   |  2005 | Waiting for table metadata lock | drop table cdr3_test_4                        |
| 45 | root | localhost | cdr3 | Query   |     0 | NULL                            | show processlist                              |
```

and the InnoDB engine status

```
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 45, OS thread handle 0x7fa3da748700, query id 170 localhost root
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 44, OS thread handle 0x7fa3da849700, query id 149 localhost root Waiting for table metadata lock
drop table cdr3_test_4
---TRANSACTION 3C05, ACTIVE 72922 sec rollback
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
ROLLING BACK 165436 lock struct(s), heap size 26458552, 96615068 row lock(s), undo log entries 56851106
MySQL thread id 39, OS thread handle 0x7fa3da94a700, query id 131 localhost root query end
insert into cdr3_test_4 select * from cdr3_v1
```

How do I interpret this? Will the drop occur when the rollback is complete? I tried to kill it within mysql by thread ID and query ID and the server couldn't find it. Is there a better way to kill it? If I kill it will it just start over?
Thanks
Mike